# Como pegar dados de dois txt diferentes, Java

Tags: java

Fala pessoal, to com um problema aqui, eu tenho dois .txt e quero criar um novo txt unindo alguns dados desses dois .txt, segue abaixo de como eu pego os dados do .txt, alguém pode me dar um caminho de como fazer isso? Tava pensando se dá pra jogar em um array os dados.

```
        scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("caminho"))
        .useDelimiter(",|\n");


        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String nome = scanner.next();
            String rg = scanner.next();
            String cpf = scanner.next();
```

Comment: qual é seu problema exatamente? ta com dificuldade de ler um arquivo? de escrever o arquivo? poderia ser mais claro?

Comment: Que tipo de união deve ser feita? Qual é o critério que determina quais entradas te um texto devem combinar com o outro? Número da linha? Ou algum outro valor de controle que está escrito nas linhas, como um índice ou um número de documento? Isso pode ser bem simples ou bem complicado de fazer, agente só vai descobrir se você esclarecer o problema.

Comment: eu quero combinar conteúdo de dois .txt, eu consigo ler utilizando o Scanner e escrever usando FileWriter, é mais ou menos igual essa dúvida porém não entendi a explicação http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411382/combine-some-elements-from-2-txt-files-into-a-third-file

Comment: Você quer simplesmente colar um texto no final do outro?

Comment: Eu tenho um .txt com 1,Nome,RG e outro com Estado,Cidade,Pais , quero criar um terceiro .txt com apenas o 1,Nome,Cidade

Comment: E qual é o fator comum entre o primeiro e o segundo texto? Tem alguma coisa dizendo qual nome mora em qual cidade?

Comment: Não tem nenhum fator necessário entre os dois, eu queria escolher um nome de um txt e uma cidade do outro gerando um txt final com a uniao dos dois

Comment: É pra ser aleatório então?

Comment: Na verdade eu precisava poder selecionar cada "campo" para montar o último

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira bacana é você usar os métodos FileWriter para criar/editar o arquivo e o FileReader para ler.

```
    public void gravar() {
            FileWriter fileWriter;
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
            try {
                fileWriter = new FileWriter("configuracoes\\config.txt");
                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                bufferedWriter.write("localhost");
                bufferedWriter.close();
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro:\n" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

---

```
public final void lerArquivo() {

        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("configuracoes\\config.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            try {
                setIP(br.readLine());
                br.close();
                setUrlPorIP(getIP());

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                BancoDeDados.database.tratamentoDeErro(ex, "");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            new File("configuracoes").mkdir();
            File f = new File("configuracoes\\config.txt");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
                gravarLinhaDeIP();
                lerArquivoConfig();
            } catch (IOException ex1) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O arquivo 'config.txt' nÃ£o existe.\n"
                //      + "Foi tentado cria-lo mas algo saiu errado.\n"
                //    + "Tente criar o arquivo Manualmente");
            }

        }

    }
```

Documentação Oficial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html